# Azure QueueClient Python can't use DefaultAzureCredential

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-sdk-python

I'm using *DefaultAzureCredential()* from *azure.identity* to get credential and use it to establish TableServiceClient (azure.data.table) connection. It works.
If I am trying to do the same for QueueClient (azure.storage.queue), I'm getting following error.
As far as I understand documentation, it should be possible to use DefailtAzureCredential() for that.

```
[2023-05-06T08:40:40.331Z] Response status: 403
Response headers:
    'Content-Length': '279'
    'Content-Type': 'application/xml'
    'Server': 'Windows-Azure-Queue/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0'
    'x-ms-request-id': '30a41a1b-a003-0004-71f6-7f25a6000000'
    'x-ms-client-request-id': 'adedb50b-ebe9-11ed-b983-001a7dda7113'
    'x-ms-version': 'REDACTED'
    'x-ms-error-code': 'REDACTED'
    'Date': 'Sat, 06 May 2023 08:40:39 GMT'
```

I'm connecting in following way. If I switch credential with storage account key, it works.

```
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
queue_service_client = QueueClient(
  account_url = os.environ["STORAGE_ENDPOINT_QUEUE"],
  credential=credential,
  queue_name  = "smsnotification"
  )

def pushNotifyToQueune(queue_service_client, playerId):
    logging.info(f"Push notify to queune")
    try:
        response = queue_service_client.send_message("m")
        logging.info(f"Print response form queune {response}")
    except:
        logging.info(f"Something goes wrong when pusing notify to queune")
        #TODO use ErrorName
```

I were trying to use Storage Account Key and it works. DefaultAzureCredential is also working for TableServiceClient but not for Queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure that your user account is assigned one of the Storage Queue related RBAC roles. Your user account must be assigned one or more of [`Storage Queue Data Contributor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-queue-data-contributor), [`Storage Queue Data Message Processor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-queue-data-message-processor), [`Storage Queue Data Message Sender`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-queue-data-message-sender), or [`Storage Queue Data Reader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#storage-queue-data-reader) roles depending on your requirements.

Comment: I did the same for Storage Table * but I've forgotten :) Thanks a lot for quick help.
Storage Account Contributor is not enough.